# If a cell in Excel contains an array formula (like `={1,2,3}`) can I extract the elements of the array with VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Like the title says, a cell `A1` contains the formula `={1,2,3}`, which is a valid input for a cell, can I use VBA to get the elements of the array.

Note that `Range("A1").Value` returns the value `1`, but `Range("A1").Formula` returns the string `={1,2,3}`. So the only way I could think of is to parse the formula and separate the values with the `,` (like CSV line).

Is there any other way to return an array of values in vba in this situation. I even tried to read it as an array into a variant with `v=Range("A1:A2").Value2` but `v(1)` contains `1` only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can first get the `FormulaArray` property of the `Range` object, then `Evaluate` it to return the full array:

```
v = Evaluate(Range("A1").FormulaArray)
```

You can access the elements as you expect (and/or manipulate them as having declared an `Array` normally):

```
v(1) --> 1
v(2) --> 2
v(3) --> 3
```